# Проблемы с кодировкой UTF-8 при работе с CSV

Tags: php, кодировка, csv, utf-8

Есть CSV файлы сохраненный в UTF-8. Я пытаюсь получить значение первого столбика вот таким способом:

```
$f = fopen(public_path('/path/file.csv'), 'r');
$columns = fgetcsv($f, null, ';');

var_dump($columns[0]);
```

Результат: `string(5) "﻿id"`. Как видите в строка `"id"`, а символов там **5**, хотя должно быть **2**. Если сделать вывод в JSON (`var_dump(json_encode($columns[0]));`), то получаю вот такой результат: `string(10) ""\ufeffid""`. Как исправить эту ситуацию и получать строку в нормальном формате `string(2) "﻿id"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас файл содержит BOM заголовок. Есть два варианта развития событий:

1. Обработать файл, [сконвертировав формат](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36739350/export-to-csv-in-utf-8-for-excel-using-php)
2. Удалить [BOM заголовок](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145035/cant-remove-ufeff-from-a-string)

В Сети так же полно примеров загрузки [CSV файла](https://gist.github.com/josephspurrier/8780545).